# Confused about time complexity of recursive function

Tags: time-complexity, dynamic-programming

For the following algorithm (this algorithm doesn't really do anything useful besides being an exercise in analyzing time complexity):

```js
const dib = (n) => {
  if (n <= 1) return;
  dib(n-1);
  dib(n-1);
```

I'm watching a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBt53YbR9Kk&t=1100s) where they say the time complexity is `O(2^n)`. If I count the nodes I can see they're right (the tree has around 32 nodes) however in my head I thought it would be `O(n*2^n)` since `n` is the height of the tree and each level has `2^n` nodes. Can anyone point out the flaw in my thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each tree has 2^i nodes, not 2^n.

So each level has 2^(i-1) nodes: 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 ... 2^n.
The deepest level is the decider in the complexity.

The total number of nodes beneath any level > 1 is 1 + 2*f(i-1) .
This is 2^n - 1.

Comment: gotcha, why does the deepest level decide the overall complexity?

Comment: That's just in this case where it is bigger than all the other levels combined. :)

Answer (score 0):

Derek's answer is great, it gives intuition behind the estimation, if you want formal proof, you can use the [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) for Decreasing functions.

> The master theorem is a formula for solving recurrences of the form
> T(n) = aT(n - b) + f(n), where a ≥ 1 and b > 0 and f(n) is
> asymptotically positive. (Asymptotically
> positive means that the function is positive for all sufficiently large n.

Recurrent formula for above algorithm is `T(n) = 2*T(n-1) + O(1)`. Do you see why? You can see solution for various cases (a=1, a>1, a<1) here http://cs.uok.edu.in/Files/79755f07-9550-4aeb-bd6f-5d802d56b46d/Custom/Ten%20Master%20Method.pdf

For our case `a>1`, so `T(n) = O(a^(n/b) * f(n)) or O (a^(n/b) * n^k )` and gives `O(2^n)`